# Python MySQL Connection Issue With `mysql-connector-python`

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to use the `mysql-connector-python` Python package to connect to a remote MySQL server. I am getting the below error. I followed the simple [Getting Started](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python#getting-started) code from GitHub.

```
2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I looked through many article and forums and tried many methods, but it still give the same error.

- I set the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0`
- Firewall set to allow MySQL port (tested with replication and connection with another server)
- I scanned the machine with nmap and made sure the port (`3306`) that I am connecting to is open.
- I tried setting `skip-name-resolve` for `[mysqld]`

**Code:**

```py
config = {
  'user': '<user>',
  'password': '<password>',
  'host': '<IP>',
  'port': <port>,
  'database': '<database>'
}

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = ('SELECT * FROM student')
    print(f'Executing Query: {query}')

    cursor.execute(query)

    for id, name in cursor:
        print(f'ID: {id}, Name: {name}')

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print('Something is wrong with your user name or password')
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print('Database does not exist')
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: You execute the cursor but you did not fetch. Try `rows = cursor.fetchall()` after the execute, then iterate over the rows to get the data.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have missed the fetch call (`fetchone()` or `fetchall()`). Try this:

```
cursor.execute(query)

rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    id = row['id']
    name = row['name']
    print(f'ID: {id}, Name: {name}')
```

Comment: i tried this and it is the same error, i think it is failing when it is trying to connect at the `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)` line.

Comment: This answer is useless: The error message indicates that there is a network problem and not a problem with cursor.

Comment: @GeorgRichter What do you suggest as a solution?